# Привязка HWID winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу сделать чтобы при первой авторизации пользователя привязывался его HWID, то есть вносился в базу данных, и при каждой авторизации он проверялся заново и если он не совпадет то авторизация не проходила.
Не хватает мозгов реализовать данную фичу.

Сейчас авторизация выглядит вот так:

```
    public partial class Login : Form
{
    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        String loginUser = textBox1.Text;
        String passUser = textBox2.Text;

        DB db = new DB();

        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = @uL AND `pass`= @uP", db.GetConnection());

        command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUser;
        command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUser;

        adapter.SelectCommand = command;
        adapter.Fill(table);

        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form1 form = new Form1();
            form.Show();

            //MessageBox.Show("YES");
        }

        else
            MessageBox.Show("No");

    }


}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Исправила тему.

Comment: если проблема с получением HWID, то ищите его через System.Management, но придётся ручками формировать из CPUID и тд и тп

Comment: Проблемы в получении нет, я хочу чтобы при авторизации HWID записывался в базу банных, после чего при каждой авторизации он проверялся. То есть я хочу понять как записывать значение и проверять его.

Comment: для вставки данных в БД используйте запрос INSERT с выполнением через метод ExecuteNonQuery(). Вот тут почитайте: https://betacode.net/10517/work-with-mysql-database-in-csharp

Comment: Я бы хотел какой то пример кода. Но спасибо за статью.

Comment: Не надо ничего писать в базу. Берете ключ продукта или сгенереный сервером на основе него токен, или хэш того или другого, или вообще пустой массив длиной к примеру 32 байта, вообще без разницы что, главное чтобы с этим позже можно было сравнить результат, шифруете это с помощью DPAPI с привязкой к текущей учетке юзера, кладете результат в файл или в реестр. Если при следующем запуске приложения удалось расшифровать - все ОК. Если не удалось или данные не найдены - значит это первый запуск приложения на этой операционной системе.

Comment: ...Если в качестве "ключа" использовать аппаратные данные (HWID), то получится еще и привязка к железу. Такую защиту невозможно обойти не внедряясь в код и/или память приложения. При этом база данных вообще не нужна. Кстати, в случае с запроса к серверу легче подменить ответ от него, чем подделать результат расшифровки DPAPI.

Comment: Прошу прощения, а есть какой то мануал или гайд по этому?

Comment: DPAPI - [ProtectedData Класс](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Смотрите только вот например, у меня пользователь например захочет сбросить свой HWID, что делать в таком случае если не будет записи в базе данных?

Comment: А если он будет в базе, то какой смысл от него, если он уже неактуален? Никакого.

Comment: Смысл в том чтобы один аккаунт ровнялся одному ПК